# Como buscar um arquivo em todas as pastas

Tags: c#, .net, diretório, sistema-de-arquivos

Como criar um aplicativo que faça uma busca completa em uma pasta ou disco procurando um arquivo quem nem na imagem
[image: Buscando...]

Já tentei utilizar
`Directory.GetFiles` e `Directory.GetDirectory`

Mas quando chega à uma pasta em que não tens acesso ele cancela toda a ação.

E mesmo assim desse jeito não houve a possibilidade de pesquisar um arquivo por nome, tamanho ou extensão.

No caso da imagem acima ele procura o disco inteiro por um arquivo chamado aria2c.exe

E quando esse aplicativo acha esse arquivo, ele começa logo depois a instalação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o que você quer é esquivar dos diretórios aos quais não tenha permissão, e continuar procurando nos diretórios que tiver permissão, terá de implementar a busca recursivamente por conta própria, um diretório por vez, e usar `try/catch` em volta das chamadas `Directory.GetFiles` e `Directory.GetDirectories`.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AcharArquivosComPermissaoRecursivamente(
    string caminhoRaiz,
    string padrao = "*.*")
{
    var caminhosPendentes = new Queue<string>();
    var arquivosAchados = new List<string>();

    caminhosPendentes.Enqueue(caminhoRaiz);

    while (caminhosPendentes.Count > 0)
    {
        var caminhoAtual = caminhosPendentes.Dequeue();

        try
        {
            var listaArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(caminhoAtual, padrao);
            arquivosAchados.AddRange(listaArquivos);

            foreach (var subDiretorio in Directory.GetDirectories(caminhoAtual))
                caminhosPendentes.Enqueue(subDiretorio);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // Ignorar exceções sobre acesso não autorizado.
        }
    }

    return arquivosAchados;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creio que sua tentativa, usando `Directory.GetDirectories()` é o começo certo.

Se está batendo em frente com exceções de accesso, necessistará de `Permissions` quando está fazendo - por exemplo, usando o `runas.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente é isto:

```
var lista = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\").GetFiles("aria2c.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

O segredo é o segundo parâmetro do [`GetFiles()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) que determina a busca recursiva com a enumeração [`SearchOption`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Se quer tratar os erros de acesso por conta própria e evitar que o método aborte pode usar uma solução como a abaixo. Curiosamente o Marc Gravel que trabalha na SE já deu várias respostas cada uma de um jeito diferente, achei [esta a mais adequada para você](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986333/221800):

```
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var file in FileUtil.GetFiles("c:\\", "aria2c.exe")) WriteLine(file);
    }
}

public static class FileUtil {
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string root, string searchPattern) {
        var pending = new Stack<string>();
        pending.Push(root);
        while (pending.Count != 0) {
            var path = pending.Pop();
            string[] next = null;
            try {
                next = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);                    
            }
            catch { } //aqui você pode colocar log, aviso ou fazer algo útil se tiver problemas
            if (next != null && next.Length != 0) foreach (var file in next) yield return file;
            try {
                next = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                foreach (var subdir in next) pending.Push(subdir);
            }
            catch { } //aqui você pode colocar log, aviso ou fazer algo útil se tiver problemas
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YDRFGN). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OuERyX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetFilesRecursive.cs).