# Copiar arquivos extensão excel de varios subdiretorios com ssis

Tags: c#, script, ssis

Eu To batendo cabeça em achar a solução para copiar arquivos de extensão excel de vários subdiretórios com ssis.

Tentei fazer com que o foreach loop container o fizesse mas não consegui, depois me repassaram um código em C# para inserir num ScripTask

```
string filtro = "*.xslx";
        string diretorioDestino = @"C:\Arquivos\Destino";

        List<string> origens = new List<string>();
        origens.Add(@"D:\ArquivosDepto1\");
        origens.Add(@"F:\ArquivosDepto3\");


        foreach (var origem in origens)
        {
            foreach (string arquivo in Directory.GetFiles(origem, filtro))
            {
                File.Copy(arquivo, Path.Combine(diretorioDestino, Path.GetFileName(arquivo)));
            }
        }
```

Comment: E qual é o problema que está tendo?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda de alguma forma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30797/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75171/101

Comment: O `Directory.GetFiles` tem um terceiro parâmetro que é `SearchOption`, passa o valor de `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. Por padrão ele vai retornar somente os arquivos do diretório especificado.

Answer (score 0):

Ednilton, o [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) retorna os nomes de arquivos (inclusive os caminhos) no diretório especificado. Para você listar todos os arquivos, inclusive os de subdiretórios, você precisa passar mais o `SearchOption`.

Bastando simplesmente você alterar o seu `foreach`

```
foreach (string arquivo in Directory.GetFiles(origem, filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

Eventualmente o `Directory.GetFiles` pode não ter permissão para acessar determinado diretório, lançando assim uma [`UnauthorizedAccessException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Uma solução seria primeiramente você pegar todos os diretórios utilizando o `GetDirectories` para depois percorrer todos os diretórios buscando os arquivos usando o `GetFiles`:

```
public static List<string> GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
{
    var diretorios = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

    List<string> arquivos = new List<string>();
    try
    {

        foreach (var diretorio in diretorios)
        {
            arquivos.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(diretorio, searchPattern, searchOption).ToList());
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {

    }

    return arquivos;
}
```

O método `Main` ficaria assim:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string filtro = "*.xlsx";
    string diretorioDestino = @"D:\temp";
    List<string> origens = new List<string>();
    origens.Add(@"C:\Users\pablotondolo\Documents");
    // 
    foreach (var origem in origens)
    {
        foreach (string arquivo in GetFiles(origem, filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Copy(arquivo, Path.Combine(diretorioDestino, Path.GetFileName(arquivo)));
        }
    }
}
```

OBS: a extenção do excel é `xlsx` e não `xslx`.

Comment: Olá, Pedro, o problema que coloco para rodar e não da nenhum erro porem não faz nada

Comment: public void Main(){   string filtro = "*.xslx"; string diretorioDestino = @"C:\Users\certeza\OneDrive\Certeza Consultoria\CLIENTES -CERTEZA\PRESERVE\Carga";List<string> origens = new List<string>();            origens.Add(@"C:\Users\certeza\OneDrive\Certeza Consultoria\CLIENTES -CERTEZA\PRESERVE\FATURAS-DLOG\");
//   origens.Add(@"F:\ArquivosDepto3\");
foreach (var origem in origens)  {
 foreach (string arquivo in Directory.GetFiles(origem, filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories))  {  File.Copy(arquivo, Path.Combine(diretorioDestino, Path.GetFileName(arquivo)));                }  }

Comment: falta um static no método Main `public static void Main(){`

Comment: ta exibindo essa mensagem :  
 at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: Então esse exemplo eu rodei em um projeto console pelo visual studio.

Comment: Pablo, eu coloquei o codigo em txt no google drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0ApY4QPh5KncWhRS3lWX19JNEE

eu to usando atraves do integration service onde tem um step de nome script task (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0ApY4QPh5KnWGxNWUI2QWZYR2c)

Comment: Não sei bem como o `ssis` funciona, vou ficar lhe devendo essa.

Comment: mesmo assim, muito obrigado por ter reservado um tempo para ajudar. Obrigado :D